# Не работает прокрутка в flet

Tags: python, android, python-3.x, прокрутка, flet

Делаю приложение под android на Python через Flet. Мне нужно отображать список заданий, однако он не всегда помещается на экране, и я решил сделать прокрутку. Однако она не работает.

Код main.py:

```
from flet import *
import views
import database as db

def main(page: Page):
    page.title = 'NeoTelecom'
    page.theme_mode = 'dark'
    page.scroll = 'adaptive'

    page.vertical_alignment = CrossAxisAlignment.START
    page.horizontal_alignment = MainAxisAlignment.CENTER

    page.window_width = 400

    page.padding = 0
    page.spacing = 0

    def route_change(e: RouteChangeEvent):
        page.views.clear()

        if page.route == '/':
            #главная страница
        
        elif page.route == '/task':
            def go_main(e):
                page.go('/main')

            def go_comment(e):
                data.data['task_id'] = e.control.data
                page.go('/task/comment')

            def go_navigate(e):
                data.data['task_id'] = e.control.data
                page.go('/task/navigate')


            view_task = views.Task(go_main, go_navigate, go_comment)
            
            #получаю tasks через api...
            
            page.views.append(view_task.view(tasks))

    page.on_route_change = route_change
    page.go(page.route)
    page.update()
    


app(target=main, assets_dir='assets/')
```

views:

```
class Task:
    def __init__(self, go_main, go_navigate, go_comment):
        self.go_main = go_main
        self.go_navigate = go_navigate
        self.go_comment = go_comment

    def task(self, task_id, status, cust_name, cust_address, cust_phone, date, _type):
        return Column(
            [
                #код для отображения одного задания
            ],
            scroll='adaptive'
        )

    def view(self, tasks):
        return View(
            route='/task',
            controls=[
                #заголовки
                        Container(
                            Column(
                                tasks,
                                alignment=MainAxisAlignment.CENTER,
                                scroll='adaptive',
                                expand=1
                            ),
                            padding=padding.only(top=20)
                        )
                    ]
                )
            ]
        )
```

Я пробовал ставить в page.scroll и в Column.scroll:

```
ScrollMode.ALWAYS;
'always';
ScrollMode.AUTO;
'auto';
ScrollMode.ADAPTIVE;
'adaptive'
```

И ничего из этого не помогло. Прокрутка через тачпад не работает, прокрутка пальцем по экрану не работает, и ползунок не появляется

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Укажи высоту или максимальную высоту для `Column`.

Скорее всего, у тебя `Column` вышла за пределами экрана.

Comment: Я попробовал установить length=800 в Column, где отображаются все задания, но это не помогло. Я не там добавил или значение надо поменять?

Comment: Установи height для Column.
У тебя не список выходит за пределами колонной а сама колонна выходит за пределами экрана. Вот и нечего ему прокручивать, потому что в колонну всё вмещается. Установи высоту для колонный и сможешь прокручивать свой список

Comment: Спасибо, все заработало!